# Conditional statement in HOCON configuration files

Tags: scala, playframework, hocon

I need to write a production.conf file for my play framework and scala application.
I have few requirements like
if <some_condition>, then username = <something_from_env>
else username = <something_else_from_env>.

I am currently using jinja2 template, which support this kind of statements. Is there a way to do the same with Play in hocon format?

Comment: We use Jinja2 template as well to do this. I don't think this is doable without an external templating or putting both keys and choosing in the code (when possible).